# Elemento não reconhecido (Download de arquivos)

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient, dropbox

Estou tentando fazer um código para baixar o arquivo em uma pasta e me retorna este erro Elemento não reconhecido.

Código:

```
string pasta = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86) + @"\teste\";
download = new WebClient();
download.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=download&export=download"), pasta+"Programa.exe");
```

O que pode ser?

Comment: Coloca o erro tbm amigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O *Google* não permite downloads dessa forma pelo *Google Drive*.

> Para fazer download de arquivos pelo Google Drive através de código,
>   você faz uma solicitação `HTTP GET` autorizada para o URL do recurso
>   do arquivo e inclui o parâmetro de consulta `alt = media`. Por
>   exemplo:
>
> ```
> GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
> ```
>
> *Autorização: Bearer*
>
> O download do arquivo requer que o usuário tenha pelo menos acesso de
>   leitura. Além disso, seu aplicativo deve ser autorizado com um escopo
>   que permita a leitura do conteúdo do arquivo. Por exemplo, um
>   aplicativo que usa o escopo `drive.readonly.metadata` não estaria
>   autorizado a baixar o conteúdo do arquivo. Os usuários com permissão
>   de edição podem restringir o download por usuários somente leitura
>   definindo o campo `viewersCanCopyContent` como `true`.
>
> Os arquivos identificados como abusivos (malware, etc.) só podem ser
>   baixados pelo proprietário. Além disso, o parâmetro de consulta
>   `acknowledledgeAbuse = true` deve ser incluído para indicar que o
>   usuário reconheceu o risco de baixar um malware em potencial. Seu
>   aplicativo deve avisar interativamente o usuário antes de usar esse
>   parâmetro de consulta.

Recomendaria que colocasse seu arquivo em outro site, como por exemplo o *Dropbox*, *Azure Blob* ou *files.fm*, onde se não me engano, não precisam de um código exótico para permitir o download de arquivos como o Google Drive.

Porém, caso queria continuar com o *Drive*, no link abaixo você confere como fazer o que deseja.

Informações retiradas de: [Google Drive APIs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

**EDIT**

Acabei passando a informação errada e no caso do Dropbox, também é necessário utilizar um `DropboxClient` para download de arquivos + um `Token` gerado pela API do *Dropbox*. Dito isso, vamos ao que interessa.

### 1. Crie uma conta no Dropbox

Entre no site do [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) e crie sua conta.

### 2. Crie um App para ter acesso ao um Token

Entre no site do [Dropbox Developers](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) e crie um App que será usado para gerar um Token para que possamos realizar o download de arquivos do Dropbox.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na tela que abrir, selecione **Dropbox API**, depois selecione **Full Dropbox**, defina um **nome para seu App** e por fim, clique em **Create App**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 3. Gere um Token

Na tela aberta, procure por **Generated access token** e clique em **Generate**. Feito isso, um Token será gerado. Salve esse **Token** em um local seguro. Ele será usado para identificar via código a sua conta **Dropbox**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 4. Crie uma pasta no Dropbox

Crie uma pasta no Dropbox e coloque o arquivo que deseja fazer o download lá dentro. Você poderá usar a mesma pasta para colocar qualquer tipo de arquivo que deseje fazer o download.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isso, adicione o(s) arquivo(s) desejado(s) dentro da pasta criada. Neste caso, coloquei um arquivo `.7z` (zip) com o nome de *cv_2018*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 5. Crie o código para download do arquivo

```
private string _token = "token_gerado_nas_etapas_anteriores";

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    btnDownload.Click += Download_Click;
}

/// <summary>
/// Click do botão para download do arquivo
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private async void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DropboxClient client;

        client = new DropboxClient(_token);
        string folder = "DownloadFiles";
        string file = "cv_2018.7z";
        string destinationFolder = @"C:\Test";

        await Download(client, folder, file, destinationFolder);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Erro ao fazer download do arquivo: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Faz o download de um arquivo do Dropbox e salva localmente
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dbx">DropboxClient</param>
/// <param name="folder">Pasta onde se encontra o arquivo no Dropbox</param>
/// <param name="file">Nome do arquivo com a extensão no Dropbox</param>
/// <param name="destinationFolder">Pasta de destino no computador</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task Download(DropboxClient dbx, string folder, string file, string destinationFolder)
{
    using (var response = await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync("/" + folder + "/" + file))
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.Create($"{destinationFolder}\\{file}"))
        {
            (await response.GetContentAsStreamAsync()).CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: E como posso fazer um link de download direto no DropBox por exemplo?

Comment: @Slinidy acabei me enganando em relação a isso e o Dropbox também requer uma forma de download de arquivos parecida com a do Google. Em breve estarei atualizando a resposta com as informações.

Comment: @Slinidy Resposta atualizada. As etapas foram testadas e o código está funcionando perfeitamente.